# Is there any API to get AWS inspector findings data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, inspector

I have configured AWS inspector template to scan AWS EC2 instance. I am able to run the inspector and get findings/data thru it.
But now I want automation/API to get the same AWS inspector findings/data in raw or JSON formatted data.

I tried with the boto3 get_assessment_report method, but able to get it only HTML or PDF format not JSON.
[link for reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/inspector.html#Inspector.Client.get_assessment_report)

Answer (score 1):

From [the page you linked](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/inspector.html#Inspector.Client.describe_findings): `describe_findings()`. I believe you will need to call `list_findings()` first, to get the ARNs for the findings you want the details of.

Answer (score 0):

AWS now launched the latest version called inspector2. The following code works for me.

```
import boto3
inspector = boto3.client("inspector2")
paginator = inspector.get_paginator("list_findings")
page_iterator = paginator.Paginate()

# Print all findings
for page in page_iterator:
   print(page["findings"])
```